# unable to query hive after adding sql server jar to pyspark's class path

Tags: sql-server, jar, pyspark, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

Hive is set up correctly, I can query it using `spark.sql` after entering the repl using `pyspark`. I want to read a table from sql server and save it to hive. If start the repl passing in a jdbc jar like `pyspark  --driver-class-path sqljdbc4.jar --jars sqljdbc4.jar` I can read from sql server. However now spark is unable to access hive. Any query on the existing hive table leads to an Lzo Codec error (see below).

I want to know how I can query/pull down an external sql server table, then save it to an existing hive table.

```
spark.sql("select max(product_id) from table").show()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 287, in show
        print(self._jdf.showString(n, truncate))
      File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
      File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
        return f(*a, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o95.showString.
    : org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
    Exchange SinglePartition
    +- *HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_max(product_id#35)], output=[max#45])
       +- HiveTableScan [product_id#35], MetastoreRelation db, table

        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange.doExecute(ShuffleExchange.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:233)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.inputRDDs(HashAggregateExec.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:361)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:240)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2193)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2546)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2192)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2199)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:1935)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:1934)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2576)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:1934)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2149)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:239)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getInputFormat(HadoopRDD.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
        at org.apache.spark.ShuffleDependency.<init>(Dependency.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange$.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchange.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchange.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchange.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchange.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
        ... 41 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 80 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Compression codec com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec not found.
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.getCodecClasses(CompressionCodecFactory.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.<init>(CompressionCodecFactory.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.configure(TextInputFormat.java:45)
        ... 85 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.getCodecClasses(CompressionCodecFactory.java:132)
        ... 87 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The --driver-class-path flag replaces any values you have configured in your default settings.  It does not append new values.  You probably have the LZO jar added to the class path in your spark-defaults.conf file and it is being ignored because you are overwriting that setting with the flag.  You should either:

1) Include the entire driver classpath in your `--driver-class-path` setting

or

2) Add the SQL JDBC jar to the classpath in the `spark.driver.extraClassPath` setting in the spark-defaults.conf file

Also, as @Tim pointed out in the comment, you still need to provide your jar to the command line using the --jars flag.

Comment: Thanks @RyanW. I think you should mention you still have to pass the jar. Then I will mark it correct.